# How to properly display a Snackbar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, snackbar

I am trying to show a `Snackbar` on click of a `floatingActionbutton`. But when I click on the `floatingactionbutton` it's not showing anything. Here is my code. I am using a `StatefulWidget`. I debugged and checked that the onPressed function is also getting executed but somehow the `Snackbar` is not visible. What can be the root cause of the issue? I feel the BuildContext I am passing has some issue.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  MyAppState createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return new MyAppState();
  }

}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{
  File _image;
  String _text;

  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    _image = image;
    final FirebaseVisionImage visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(_image);
    final TextRecognizer textRecognizer = FirebaseVision.instance.textRecognizer();
    final VisionText visionText = await textRecognizer.processImage(visionImage);

    String detectedText = visionText.text;

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
      _text = detectedText;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Image Picker Example'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: _image == null
              ? new Text('No image selected.')
              : new Image.file(_image),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: (){
            showSnackBar(context);
//            getImage();
          },
          tooltip: 'Pick Image',
          child: new Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showSnackBar(BuildContext context) {
    final scaffold = Scaffold.of(context);
    final snackBarContent = SnackBar(
      content: Text("sagar"),
      action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'UNDO', onPressed: scaffold.hideCurrentSnackBar),
    );
    scaffold.showSnackBar(snackBarContent);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That happens because the `BuildContext` used has not a `Scaffold` ancestor thus, won't be able to find it to render a `SnackBar` since it's up to the `Scaffold` to display it.

According to the [of method](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold/of.html) documentation:

> When the Scaffold is actually created in the same build function, the
> context argument to the build function can't be used to find the
> Scaffold (since it's "above" the widget being returned). In such
> cases, the following technique with a Builder can be used to provide a
> new scope with a BuildContext that is "under" the Scaffold:
>
> ```
> @override
> Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>   return Scaffold(
>     appBar: AppBar(
>       title: Text('Demo')
>     ),
>     body: Builder(
>       // Create an inner BuildContext so that the onPressed methods
>       // can refer to the Scaffold with Scaffold.of().
>       builder: (BuildContext context) {
>         return Center(
>           child: RaisedButton(
>             child: Text('SHOW A SNACKBAR'),
>             onPressed: () {
>               ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
>                 content: Text('Hello!'),
>               ));
>             },
>           ),
>         );
>       },
>     ),
>   );
> }
> ```

**Solution**

Wrapping your `FloatingActionButton` in a `Builder` widget will make it possible in a more elegant way than using a `GlobalKey`, which was already mentioned by the @Epizon answer.

Answer (score 11):

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  MyAppState createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return new MyAppState();
  }

}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldkey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  File _image;
  String _text;

  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    _image = image;
    final FirebaseVisionImage visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(_image);
    final TextRecognizer textRecognizer = FirebaseVision.instance.textRecognizer();
    final VisionText visionText = await textRecognizer.processImage(visionImage);

    String detectedText = visionText.text;

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
      _text = detectedText;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldkey,
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Image Picker Example'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
          child: _image == null
              ? new Text('No image selected.')
              : new Image.file(_image),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: (){
            showSnackBar();
//            getImage();
          },
          tooltip: 'Pick Image',
          child: new Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showSnackBar() {
    final snackBarContent = SnackBar(
      content: Text("sagar"),
      action: SnackBarAction(
          label: 'UNDO', onPressed: _scaffoldkey.currentState.hideCurrentSnackBar),
    );
    _scaffoldkey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBarContent);
  }



}
```

Answer (score 4):

To show **SnackBar** You can use like this:

```
 ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text('User Logged In'),
        ));
```

Previous **SnackBar** was used like this:

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                content: Text('Rahul Kushwaha!'),
              ));
```

**Now**, SnackBar is managed by ***ScaffoldMessenger***. For details study this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger)

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue when trying to `showSnackbar()` in `StatfulWidget` from second level child of the parent `Parent() => childLevel1 => childOfLevel1(){showing the snackbar here}`

I implemented @Epizon answer but `.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBarContent);` was deprecated, According to flutter:

> The SnackBar API within the Scaffold is now handled by the ScaffoldMessenger
> read  full document

so replacing this line in @Epizon answer:
`_scaffoldKey.currentState!.showSnackBar(_snackBarContent);`

to this:
`ScaffoldMessenger.of(_scaffoldKey.currentState!.context) .showSnackBar(_snackBarContent);`

will solve the deprecation issue

here is the code

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

    void _showSnack(String msg) {
      final _snackBarContent = SnackBar(content: Text(msg));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(_scaffoldKey.currentState!.context)
          .showSnackBar(_snackBarContent);     
    }

return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        //resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Center(
child: ElevatedButton(
child: Text("show snackbar"),
onPressed(){_showSnack("im located in the btn's onPressed");},
);
);
```